# Flink Jobmanager not able to see task managers

Tags: ssh, cluster-computing, apache-flink

So I've installed an apache flink cluster on our network. I've done the configurations as illustrated below. This Master (JobManager) starts, and sends the start command to all the slaves via ssh. I can see that the task managers are running after they were started by the master node.

Config file on all nodes:

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: flmaster
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
jobmanager.heap.mb: 1024
taskmanager.heap.mb: 2048
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 1
taskmanager.memory.preallocate: false
parallelism.default: 1
jobmanager.web.port: 8081
taskmanager.tmp.dirs: /apps/storage/runtime/flink/workspace
recovery.mode: zookeeper
recovery.zookeeper.quorum:zk1:2181, zk2:2181, zk3:2181 
recovery.zookeeper.storageDir: /apps/runtime/flink/recovery
env.java.home: /apps/java/
```

Then i have a file called slaves in the config folder with a list of the slaves nodes.

```
flSlave1
flSlave2
flSlave3
```

I then start it

```
../bin/start-cluster.sh
```

This opens an ssh session to all the slave nodes, and starts the task manager. I can see this with ps ax | grep java

I can open the Web-Ui on flMaster:8081
On the WebUI I can see the slave node count is 0. I have no task managers. 
As a test, I started the wordcount.jar job, and it tells me it cannot run the job since there are no slots open.

```
/apps/flink/bin/flink run /apps/flink/examples/batch/WordCount.jar
```

the response:

```
07/20/2016 13:19:01     Job execution switched to status FAILING.
org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Not enough free slots available to run the job.*
```

Well I guess if there is no task managers/slave nodes, there will be no slots.

Any one ever seen this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fully qualified hostname instead of short name. For e.g hostname.xyx.com instead of just hostname. OR you could also try using ip address.

Comment: Wow this was a blast from the past. Yeah that is how I ended up to solve it. I used the IP. a bit of a bad habit, since even static IP will change for whatever reason eventually. (like network team gets an itch to redo the network etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a telnet on jobmanager machine rpc port. The taskmanagers talk with jobmanager through rpc. So check the network settings whether you are able to access the jobmanager and task managers' rpc ports or not.

Also check the blob server port. Check the taskmanager logs whether it is able to connect to the jobmanager blob server or not.